# Usar angular dentro de un proyecto de JAVA + STRUTS

Tags: java, angular, maven, struts

Tengo un proyecto hecho en Java + Struts 1 el cual funciona bien junto Maven y un servidor JBOSS. Ahora necesito pasarlo a angular, no de manera completa de momento sino un prototipo, o sea, hacer que las llamadas y peticiones de datos que se hacian mediante el enrutamiento que hacia STRUT con los JSP, esta vez se aplique con angular.
Se que hay una libreria llamada GSON que permite hacer la coneccion entre JAVA y ANGULAR, pero el tema es que no se como combinar las tecnologias ya que usan servidores distintos, es decir, para poder ingresar al sistema original en strut, debo iniciar el server JBOSS para que cargue todas las dependencias que me permitan acceder y loguearme, pero no se como meter una pagina en angular entre medio ya que esta necesita de otro servidor propio.

Alguno tendra una idea como puedo implementar siquiera una pantalla que funcione en angular dentro de ese proyecto en JAVA + Struts?

muchas gracias!!!

Answer (score 1):

Angular es un framework que encierra dentro de si mismo todo lo que struts propone como componente web, dejando solo para el backend, el procesamiento estricto del negocio, en ese orden de ideas lo que debes hacer para lograr esa integracion es que Struts renderize el tag root de angular y a partir de ahi que angular se comunique a el servidor a traves de servicios, que en este caso deberas adaptar con base a las funcionalidades de negocio que manejes, es un cambio fuerte porque es cambio tanto en el cliente como en el servidor, en el cliente porque implica programar la parte de angular como en el servidor creando los servicios(habitualmente REST, o websocket), no olvidando que a los servicios que se expongan hay que ajustarles temas como la seguridad.

Comment: Muchas gracias, de que manera podria hacerse la renderizacion de el root mediante strut?, es necesario tener los dos servidores paralelamente funcionando?

Comment: Entre sus herramientas Angular provee un servidor web, para no depender de otras implementaciones de servidor, el cual en este caso ya usted tiene con el servidor jboss, solo coloque los archivos que se necesitan para angular como recursos dentro del servidor y asegurese de cargar el index, de ahi para alla angular trabaja solo desde que tenga todas sus dependencias adsequibles

Comment: Yo te puedo decir que si quieres integrar angular (en un servidor) y java+struts1 (en otro servidor) no te va a funcionar a menos que desaparezcas struts1 y el front-end este en angular y el back end en java webservices. Si quieres integrar las 3 tecnologias deben vivir en el mismo servidor.

Comment: preguntas basadas en opiniones, ayúdanos a mantener la calidad del sitio